# Apply a formula to each cell in column before computing a sum of the cells

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

How could I apply a formula to each cell in a column before computing a sum of the cells in Google spreadsheet?

In other words, I have a column of cells with numbers. And what I want is to iterate over each row in the column (i.e. each cell), apply a formula to the number in the cell and get a result of the formula. Then I want to sum all of those results.

And all of this I would like to perform in one cell (i.e. in one query).

Comment: what formula you want to apply?

Comment: @MARKMYANSWER, I want to calculate the variance manually (I am aware of the `VAR` function). Thank you.

Comment: I wasn't referring to `VAR` function... you say: `"apply a formula to the number in the cell and get a result of the formula. Then I want to sum all of those results."` and I ask: what formula you want to apply to the number in the cell before you sum the results of this application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA((B2:B26-$B$1)^2))/A1
```

[image]

---

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(A1:A4*(SUM(2, 3))))
```

[image]